# Magento 2.4 - Move product-add-form to customer div class

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.4, addtocart

Is there any way to move the "product-add-form" to a new customer class?

I have added in the catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.add.form" destination="product.info.rechts" before="-"/>
```

But it is not working...

PriceBox and Social Links are working...

```
<move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.rechts" before="-"/>
<move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.rechts" after="-"/>
```

Any idea? Thank you so much

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Element `product.add.form` doesn't exist, you can try `product.info.addtocart` instead.